# Google fun facts + angular

Tags: angularjs, web

From my understanding, Google has reacently provided a new search service.
To access this you simply "google": **fun facts** or **i'm feeling curious**

But is there a simple way to extract the information since I can't find an API for this?

I was simply trying this with angular 1.6 like this:

```
function getFunFact(){
    var URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=fun+facts";
    $http.get(URL)
    .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (e) {
          console.log(e);
    });
}
```

But I only get the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) error. Is there a way to bypass this to access the information via CSS selectors etcetera?

**Update:**

The suggested plug-in will work for now.

But is there an easy way to grab the content from the html document response?
It's just a long string, e.g:

! doctype html  html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="sv" head .................................................................................................. /html>

Or is google preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding the CORS extension in my chrome

(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

Just enable this extension whenever you want allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin' header request.